# Running bash commands with quotes from SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

> Reference: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Process.html

As per the above documentation, users can write bash commands to run from SBT. I'm trying to run the following command containing quotes and its NOT working:

```
"mongo test -eval \"db.dropDatabase()\"" !
```

Whenever I try to run any bash command containing quotes, then it fails to execute them and just prints whatever is within the double quotes.

Comment: It worked for me, I did not get any error. `scala> import sys.process._
import sys.process._

scala> "mongo test -eval \"db.dropDatabase()\"" !
warning: there was one feature warning; re-run with -feature for details
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: test
db.dropDatabase()
res5: Int = 0`

Comment: You'd better use the call where the parameter are given a `Seq[String]`, so there is no need to manage the space delimiter and quote: `Process("ls" :: "-l" :: Nil, Path.userHome, "key1" -> value1, "key2" -> value2)`

Comment: Using `Process` instead of munging strings fixed my issues. Thanks :)